# Expose .NET Method via COM with Alternate Name

Tags: c#, .net, com, com-interop

I am exposing a .NET class and its members via COM, using this attribute
`[ComVisible(True)]`

Is there a way of exposing a method or other member with a different name?  For example, in Json serialization, this can be done with the following manner?

`[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "FooBar")]`

Is there something comparable with exposing via COM?

One reason why I'd want this is in the event of method overloads, I'd have more meaningful names than SomeMethod_1 and SomeMethod_2.  But there may be other benefits too.

Comment: Write a new method having the ComVisible attribute, and the name you want to expose, that calls the original method?

Comment: Why do you get SomeMethod_1 and SomeMethod_2 in the first place? How do you define your methods?  How do you define the class (ClassInterfaceAttribute), etc?

Comment: @SimonMourier ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual) for class.  Method are just standard overloads

Comment: COM doesn't support methods overloads. If you want non-generated names, you'll have to come up with different names for methods. One option, if you still want overloads in .NET, is to 1) define a COM interface (in .NET), with different names, 2) implement it explicitly in the class through overload, and 3) use ClassInterfaceType.None for the class